# Visual Studio 2012 Signing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-signing, post-build-event

I would like to have Visual Studio sign my assemblies.

I got past the point where I can specify my PFX file without any complaints.  That was not easy, as I had two of errors.  Yes, I had to make sure that I used openssl (a stackoverflow article helped with that error) and a microsoft article helped with the first error message, where I had to import the PFX file, clear/set options, and then reexport to not include downstream certificates.

When I go to build a project, I receive the warning:

> Option 'keycontainer' overrides attribute 'System.Reflection.AssemblyKeyNameAttribute' given in a source file or added module"

Naturally, my assembly did not get signed.

I did some research and the best suggestion that I saw was to add a line to the project file (did not help) or to sign stuff manually using a post build event, which I am now doing, but I would still like to get the sign tool to work.

I cannot imagine that Microsoft would offer the Singing tab, if the vast majority of developers would not be able to use the feature.

Heck, with the new Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 release, I would have expected that signing assemblies (DLLs or EXEs) would be child's play.  The task is anything but.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Without more information, I can't tell if this will fix your issue. But I'll post the answer that worked for me. In my case, I had converted an old project (pre VS 2012) that had specified signing in the AssemblyInfo.cs file like so...

```
[assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false)]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("")]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyName("")]
```

I usually use the Signing tab in project/properties as you describe. The warning message was essentially saying "Hey, you already told me something different in the source code!"

The solution for me was to remove the above three lines in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.
I realize this is probably way after your original post but I hope someone finds it useful.